# Оператор += в Java

Tags: java, операторы

До настоящего времени я считал, что запись

```
i += j;
```

есть то же самое, что и

```
i = i + j;
```

Однако если взять

```
int i = 5;
long j = 8;
```

То выражение `i = i + j` не скомпилируется, в то время как `i += j` будет компилироваться без проблем.

Означает ли, что `i += j` эквивалентно чему-то вроде `i = (type of i) (i + j)`?

Comment: Этот вопрос (так же как и ответ) взят с [английского SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ответ можно найти в спецификациях Java, [§15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> Присваивание вида `E1 op= E2` эквивалентно выражению `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, где T — тип E1. Отличие состоит лишь в том, что E1 вычисляется только один раз.

Далее, там есть следующий пример:

> Данный код является корректным:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;
> x += 4.6;
> ```
>
> В результате получаем для `x` значение 7, так как это эквивалентно:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;
> x = (short)(x + 4.6);
> ```

Другими словами, ваши догадки верны.